# Read from list in contet

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm very new to python and I'm trying to do a basic api request using the requests library, but I'm having some trouble reading a list in the returned body.

The body of my response looks like this:

```
{
    "files": [{
        "url": "http://someurl.json",
        "lastModified": 1470924180000
    }]
}
```

With my code I get the data contained in "files", but I can't figure out how to get the data conatained in "url".
My code:

```
response = requests.get(url)  
data = response.json()  
print(data["files"])
```

This returns:

```
[{'url': 'http://myurl.json', 'lastModified': 1470928985000}]
```

How can I store the url and lastModified in variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply with:

```
url = data['files'][0]['url']
last_modified = data['files'][0]['lastModified']
```

your data is a dictionary that contains a `list` of dictionaries for the  `"files"` key. To get the first entry of `files` you must index the list with `data['files'][0]`.

After that `data['files'][0]` is a dictionary which you can again access by key name as required, in this case `'url'` and `'lastModified'`.

Comment: Thanks!  
That explains why it didn't work when I tried with data['files']['url']

Comment: @user45706 Exactly, notice how `"files"` is structured, it has a square bracket first `[` indicating a list, then a curly bracket `{` indicating a dictionary. Since the dictionary is inside the list, you must index the list to get it.